# one-to-one unidirectional hibernate mapping is not creating foreign key while table creation

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, orm

anyone tell me where I am wrong. Already had wasted a day.
Problem is why hibernate(v 3.5.0 FINAL) is not creating foreign key in cdl_group_module table? It just create table having only single column i.e id(PK). I want one-to-one unidirectional mapping. I can not use bi-directional mapping because cdl_group is also used by other tables same as for cdl_module.

Below is my POJO.

```
public class CDLGroupModule extends AbstractDomainObject {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Group group;
    private CDLModule cdlModule;

    /**
     * @return the group
     */
    public Group getGroup() {
        return group;
    }

    /**
     * @param group
     *            the group to set
     */
    public void setGroup(Group group) {
        this.group = group;
    }

    /**
     * @return the cdlModule
     */
    public CDLModule getCdlModule() {
        return cdlModule;
    }

    /**
     * @param cdlModule
     *            the cdlModule to set
     */
    public void setCdlModule(CDLModule cdlModule) {
        this.cdlModule = cdlModule;
    }

}


public class Group extends AbstractDomainObject{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String name;
    private String description;

    public Group() {
    }

    public Group(String name, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    /**
     * @return the description
     */
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    /**
     * @param description the description to set
     */
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[Group : { id : " + id + ", name : " + name + ", description :" + description + " }]";
    }

}


public class CDLModule extends AbstractDomainObject {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private CdlModuleEnum module;

    /**
     * @return the module
     */
    public CdlModuleEnum getModule() {
        return module;
    }

    /**
     * @param module
     *            the module to set
     */
    public void setModule(CdlModuleEnum module) {
        this.module = module;
    }

}
```

Below is my hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.qait.cdl.commons.domain">
    <class name="CDLGroupModule" table="cdl_group_module">

        <id name="id" type="long" column="id">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>

         <!-- <many-to-one name="group" cascade="all" fetch="join"
            lazy="false" class="Group" not-null="true" unique="true"/>

        <many-to-one name="cdlModule" cascade="all" fetch="join"
            lazy="false" class="CDLModule" not-null="true" unique="true"/> -->

        <one-to-one name="group" cascade="all-delete-orphan" fetch="join"
            lazy="false" class="Group" />

        <one-to-one name="cdlModule" cascade="all-delete-orphan" fetch="join"
            lazy="false" class="CDLModule" />


    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Hibernate created **cdl_group** and **cdl_module** table already successfully. My **id** property is present in **AbstractDomainObject** class which all POJO's are extending. If I tried **many-to-one mapping using unique=true** instead of **one-to-one mapping** than hibernate doesn't even create table.
What is the reason behind that?
Any kind of help will be appreciable. You can ask if you want more info from my side.

Comment: can you post ypur 'CDLModule' entity and mapping?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that hibernate for one to one will try to map on the PK. When fetching cdl_group_module it will try to populate the relationship with any cdl_group with the same PK as the PK of cdl_group_module. This gets pretty bogey when you remove and add new cdl_group enities.

Try setting this property to create a FK:
"property-ref (optional): the name of a property of the associated class that is joined to the primary key of this class. If not specified, the primary key of the associated class is used."